# Launch QTP on remote machine using C#

Tags: c#, automation, qtp, remote-server

I am trying to launch QTP on a remote machine using C# code. Below is the code i am using to invoke QTP on local machine. I know that we can invoke QTP using VBS by adding the remote Server IP address as below. Can someone please let me know where to add the Server IP address to my C# code below to launch QTP on remote machine and run the test cases?

**VBS Code**

```
Dim qtApp
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application","Server IP Address")
```

**C# Code i wanted to implement**

```
protected void btnExecuteScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          QuickTest.Application QTPInstance = new QuickTest.Application();
          QTPInstance.Launch();
          QTPInstance.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a remote object in C# you need to get the remote `Type` first.

```
Type remoteQTP = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("QuickTest.Application", "Server IP Address");
QuickTest.Application qtp = (QuickTest.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(remoteQTP);

qtp.Launch();
qtp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Hi Motti, Thanks for your answer. I am getting the error below after executing the code. Can you please help me if you know about this error. Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B9B8E92-EBAA-44AF-A23C-9FBD08EAFA54} from machine <Server IP address> failed due to the following error: 80070005.

Comment: @user545359 that error means **Access is denied**, does the `CreateObject` in VBS work?

Comment: Actually create object in VBS is not working as well. So I did some research on this and found that firewall port needs to be opened between our servers to communicate as well as I will need to be given permission for our QTP server. Once this setup is done I will try it and will let you know. Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Motti, if you don't mind I have one more question on QTP. In this link I have asked a question related to QTP can you please take a look at this and let if know if this is something that's possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179496/can-we-pass-data-to-qtp-script-through-c-sharp-as-parameters

Comment: @user545359 sorry I don't know.